# DCGANの実装のpaddingに関して

Tags: python, tensorflow, 機械学習, keras

現在DCGANをkerasで実装しようとしているのですが、generatorの最初ところ(1024,4,4)を(1,1)の大きさのカーネルをストライド5で(512,8,8)へ逆畳み込みしていますよね？
kerasのConv2DTransposeを使おうと思っているのですが、その際、paddingはsameかvalidどのようにしたらいいですか？また(4,4)のサイズにカーネルのストライド5は大丈夫なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

padding = "same"を指定すると出力の大きさが変わらないようになるので、padding = "valid"で良いと思います。
実験してないのでなんとも言えませんが(4,4)にstrides = 5は無理があると思います。モデルの性能的にも、です。